# React Router: Authenticated Route Redirection Issue

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

I'm encountering an issue with React Router where I'm trying to implement authentication for my application using React Router's Route components. I have an Auth component that checks the user's authentication status by making an asynchronous request to my server's /users/check-auth endpoint. If the user is authenticated, it should render the protected routes using , otherwise, it should redirect to the login page.

This is my Auth.jsx

```
function Auth() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${base}/users/check-auth`, {
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, [navigate]);

  return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Login />;
}
```

These are my Routes

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Toaster richColors position="top-center" />
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route element={<Auth />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/user-details" element={<UserDetails />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this code is in Login.jsx

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userDetails = {
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
    };
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${base}/users/login`, userDetails);
      toast.success(response.data.message);
      Cookies.set("aToken", response.data.data.accessToken, {
        expires: 1,
        path: "",
      });
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error.response.data.message);
    }
  };
```

after this didn't work, i tried different appraoch using reducer where i set isloggedin status to true after a successfull login and then use it in auth.jsx to check whether the user is authenticated or not, this was the code for it:

```
const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  let token = Cookies.get("aToken") || isLoggedIn;
  if (!token) {
    return <Login />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
```

also there is this problem in the above code aswell. It didn't work if i used only cookies or only isLoggedIn. I had to use both in order to make it work. https://daisyui.onrender.com/ this was achieved using both cookies and islogged in. i want to understand what is the problem. i think it has something to do with batch updates of react or maybe something else that i dont know of. Please help me with it.